# python3 Path stitching error of os moudle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

python3   Path stitching error of os moudle?
How to solve？

```
import os
os.path.join(r'F:\django\aa',r'/media/2.png')
```

reslt
F:/media/2.png

expect
F:\django\aa\media\2.png

in django

```
from django.conf import settings
import os
os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'/media/2.png')
```

Answer (score 2):

The second path must not start with `/`.

```
>>> os.path.join(r'F:\django\aa',r'/media/2.png')
'/media/2.png'
>>> os.path.join(r'F:\django\aa',r'media/2.png')
'F:\\django\\aa/media/2.png'
```

If it does, the entire first path except the drive will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

For simple approach you can try this.

`import os
print(os.path.join('F:\django\\aa', 'media\\2.png'))`